# Autofilter multiple fields with OR condition

Tags: vba, excel

Is there any way to apply or conditions when auto filtering multiple fields in vba?

For example:

```
Field 1 | Field 2 | Field 3
   A    |    1    |    2
   B    |    3    |    4
   C    |    5    |    6
```

I am looking for a solution so I can filter Field 2 = 1 OR Field 3 = 4 to get the following output:

```
Field 1 | Field 2 | Field 3
   A    |    1    |    2
   B    |    3    |    4
```

Comment: Not using the built-in AutoFilter, unless you want to create a "helper" column and filter on that

Comment: As Tim Williams suggested you can add another column like: `=OR(B2=1, C2=4)` and copy all the way down.

Comment: Adding a helper column is not an option due to requirement restrictions. I was thinking along the line of storing a list of "qualified" row# into an arraylist but am not sure if that's efficient. Any thoughts?

Comment: Then you need to do it through VBA, is this an option for you?

Comment: Yes. Definitely comfortable with going through vba.

Comment: You can define your range and loop through rows from end to start and hide the rows like this: `If Cells(i, 2) <> 1 And Cells(i, 3) <> 4 Then Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = True`

Comment: That makes a lot of sense :) Thanks